# Its better to put Symfony 2 in the "root" of the website (www) or in a sub-folder?

Tags: symfony, web, root

Its better to put Symfony 2 in the "root" of the website (www) or in a sub-folder? And why?

**Method 1**

```
mysite/www/...
```

**Method 2**

```
mysite/www/symfony2/...
```

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to put `Symfony` folder **outside** of root web server's folder because only `web` folder of `Symfony` is meant to be public. By putting whole `Symfony` folder under root folder of web server you make all files public.

So best solution is to put `Symfony` folder somewhere outside web server's root folder (like `/home/developer/symfonyProject`) and then make symbolic link to `web` folder somewhere under web server root folder (does not really matter if in root folder or sub folder)

```
/home/developer/
├─ symfonyProject/
│  ├─ app
│  ├─ (...)
│  └─ web/
/var/www/
├─ symfony (this is link to /home/developer/symfonyProject/web)
```

Comment: If i understand, I have to create a Symfony project in `/home/developer/` and in `/home/mySite/www/` I create a symbolic link to `/home/developer/symfonyProject/web` ?