# Why should we keep index.php in the public folder instead of in the root?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, zend-framework

I still don't quite understand why we must keep index.php in a public directory instead of in the root directory.

```
root/of/project
    public/
       index.php
       .htacess
       (html, image, css, etc)
```

Then, write the following in our virtual host file:

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/myapp/app/public
<Directory "/path/to/myapp/app/public">
  # other setting here
</Directory>
```

The .htaccess file then redirects all non-existing URLs to index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I notice that most frameworks do so, such as Symfony and Zend, just as [this](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/php-bootstrapping-crash-course/146) tutorial. What is the actual **benefits** really by having the trouble of modifying the virtual host file?

Why shouldn't we do have this below instead **without** modifying the virtual host file? Is it a security risk or something?

```
root/of/project    
    index.php
    .htacess
    public/ 
       (html, image, css, etc)
```

If keeping index.php and modifying the virtual host file is better, **how** can we modify the virtual host file in the **live server** then? Let's say I have this domain name, http://my-website.com/ and I access it on my browser, what I see first is not the web page but the directories below untill I click the public directory then I see the home page,

```
root/of/project
    public/
       index.php
       .htacess
       (html, image, css, etc)
```

I assume that this is the same for Zend or Symfony project as well without being able to modify the virtual host file in the live server. I am no good at these frameworks, I will see this below if I upload my Zend project to the live server,

[image]

So, **how do you deploy** your Zend or Symfony project to your live server to see your web page right away?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a very good idea to keep `index.php` **outside** of your project root directory because of one simple reason:

You don't want your user to access any files other that one in public folder (index.php, css, js etc). When you will put index.php in root folder you will be also able to access `composer.json` file for example which is a security risk - a potential hacker will know what packages are you using, in which versions so it's easier for him to perform attack.

When it comes to your hosting - you should have some `public_html` folder on your root directory which is meant to be public folder (web) of your `Symfony` app and you should also be able to keep files outside of public folder. If you don't - you really need to think about changing hosting partner

**EDIT**: 
Answering your comment. Let's assume you have `public_html` folder on your hosting and you want to deploy `Symfony` app which should be accessible directly on `http://your-domain.com`. Then you should put whole `Symfony` project anywhere (but outside of `public_html` folder) and make a `public_html` folder a symbolic link to `web` folder of your `Symfony` project. This action is equivalent of editing virtual host and changing `DocumentRoot` which, I assume, you are not able to do.

You can also check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116956/its-better-to-put-symfony-2-in-the-root-of-the-website-www-or-in-a-sub-folde/29117041#29117041) on another question to get more clarification

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes some of my hosting servers have this `public_html` folder. Do you mean that I should keep the 'public/' of Symfony or Zend in that folder only while the 'src/' and everything else outside that `public_html` folder?